# Do we remain unconscious or conscious after death

Tags: vedas, krishna, bhagavad-gita, atma, consciousness

While I was search about Hinduism on internet, I got to know 2 contradictory facts.

One said that we get unconscious after death for 2 to 3 months as we become while sleeping,

Other said that we remain conscious and if it is true then we see different loks se atman after death like yamalok etc.

I got a bit confused whether we remain conscious after death or not please tell.

Comment: Based on karma either we go to different loka but a momentary enlightementh is given to jiva to remember past birth and his actions

Comment: My question is different from what you answered sir

Comment: I believe I said yes to your second part of question